# issues using chosen jquery

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-chosen

I've used the library before, and I remember there being some little problem I didn't notice, and eventually figured out. But for the life of me, I just cannot recall what it was.

I have chosen.js in the head like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<script src="/assets/js/chosen.js">
```

And am initializing it like this:

```
<script>
    $(".chosen-select").chosen()
</script>
```

I tried initializing it before and after chosen.js, and neither worked.

Last time, I had it set to apply to all  boxes instead of just those with `.chosen-select`. If I recall, I just did `$("select").chosen()`, and I tried it this time, it did not work either.

And besides getting it to work, I wanted to ask if it's possible for Chosen to automatically determine the "type" of select box when it's set to initialize for all `<select>` boxes, such as single or multiple selection without it having to be specified with a class.

I appreciate any assistance,

Comment: What is the output of `console.log( jQuery.fn.chosen );` after including `chosen.js`? It should print the plugin-code to the console.

Comment: Add your script in a dom ready handler and see `jQuey(function(){$(".chosen-select").chosen();})` - also don't forget to add the css file

Comment: Unfortunately, none of that works. And I do have the css file in place.

Comment: @feeela I actually don't know what you mean. I have firebug and I'm in the console tab, but nothing shows.

Answer (score 1):

These steps basically makes it work. Add the files from the chosen plugin at the head section

Add this in the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".chosen-select").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

and just specify `class='chosen-select'` where the select tag is present in the html code.

Theres nothing really apart from this to make it work. You have not added the chosen.css file as an external style sheet here.